# How git lfs clone is difference from git shallow clone

Tags: git, git-lfs

git lfs will only download the latest version of binary files to the local repo. However, git shallow clone downloads the latest version of all the files(source + binary).

If storage is not a concern, we can use git shallow clone over git lfs?

Answer (score 2):

You could.

But since [Git lfs 2.2.0 (May 2017)](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commit/42b4d53428680baf1b67984cd8c6c99b91747ecd), you can also use [`--shallow-since`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---shallow-sinceltdategt) in your `git lfs clone` command ([issue 2250](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2250)).

That would combine both.